# Getting a 500 Internal server error on my flask application, does not kill process running on a particular port when application is stopped

Tags: python, api, flask, taskkill

When I run the app for the first time, it is working fine but when I stop the app and try to run it again, then it gives error "Internal server error, server overloaded". It is due to the process running on that port does not get killed when the app is stopped.

I run my Flask app by,

```
app.run(port=5555)
```

And I don't want to do **app.debug = True** Any help on how to kill the process when the app is stopped, without debug = on

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the port using this command:

```
 lsof -i:<port_number>
 kill -9 <pid>
```

In your case, you can use something like this:

```
 lsof -i:5555
 kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: Then I need to do this manually every time when I stop my Python/Flask app, I want to do it automatically whenever the app is stopped.

Comment: Ok, then could you let me know which editor you are using?